# batch or vbs - find file in random folder and write on it

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I wish to realize a script which :

1) the script find a file with is name is "config.js" in a random directory

For example the file can be situated in "C:\1erg9r1f\config.js" or "C:\5rg9f26e\config.js". Or other randompaths...

2) When the script found the file, i wish automaticaly add 2 lines at the end of this file

2 lines to add in the file :

```
preferences.proxy: http://fw

preferences.proxy.https: https://fw
```

3) If the script finds the file in 2 folder, the script must add lines in theses 2 config.js files

Have you an idea to how i can realize this script?
Sorry for my bad English, I am French... lol :)

Comment: searching for a file everywhere in the drive will require a lot of time...

Comment: Where's your working? Need to see some attempt at approaching the problem yourself.

Comment: Are you only going one folder into the ` C:\ ` drive? Like if its only ever in `C:\randomNumbers\config.js` and not in `C:\stuff\randomNumbers\config.js` that can take a lot less time to sift through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /d /r "c:\"  %%a in (*) do (
 if exist "%%~fa\config.js" (
  echo file found "%%~fa\config.js"
  (echo(preferences.proxy: http://fw)>>"%%~fa\config.js"
  (echo(preferences.proxy.https: https://fw)>>"%%~fa\config.js"
 )
)
```

But be prepared to wait a lot.

If it the file only in first level folder on c: you can try also this (not tested):

```
pushd "c:\"
for /d %%a in ("*") do (
  if exist "%%~fa\config.js" (
      (echo(preferences.proxy: http://fw)>>"%%~fa\config.js"
      (echo(preferences.proxy.https: https://fw)>>"%%~fa\config.js"
 )
)
```

Comment: I think the first method is a good idea because i dont know where are files "config.js 

It's OK but i must add an other line which contain some "(" and ")" and with it, the script didnt work correctly

i want to put one more line like this :
user_pref("network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris", "https:// fw");

Comment: @S.Jeremy  - just add another echo line that looks like `(echo((user_pref("network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris", "https:// fw"^);)` (notice the caret)

Comment: Thanks for reply It's OK now. But stay one problem, when i run the script, it create a file "config.js" in folders where before execution batch "config.js" not exist.

Comment: @S.Jeremy - and you are using the first script?

Comment: @S.Jeremy - try it now.I've added additional check